# Channels for Java, Java EE, C#, asp.net and SOA

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, jakarta-ee, soa

What are the Freenode irc channels for Java, Java EE, C#, asp.net and SOA?

Comment: Which network are you thinking of? Freenode (http://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml) usually have good programming channels for every language.

Comment: @Fredrik_jakob: Yes, I am thinking of Freenode. edited.

Comment: I tried to join a channel of #Java at Freenode, but it was authorized and required an invitation. I am seeking for open channel.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Available servers: [Freenode servers](http://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml)

- Java: `##java`
- C#: `##csharp`
- ASP.NET: `##asp.net`

Looks a bit more tricky to find a SOA-channel though.

[Search irc](http://searchirc.com/) could be a good way to search for channels on either global or specific networks. Usually [Google](http://www.google.se/) works good with a quick search with some keywords, for example; "Java irc freenode".

Comment: Unless you're a university graduate fully versed in all facets of the wealth of human knowledge, I wouldn't recommend Freenode ##csharp. That place is 99% toxic. There's only 1 person there who comes to mind as helpful.